# How to link JRE.framework in swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, j2objc, j2objc-gradle

I create a swift framework with objectiveC code which are translated by j2objc.

I have add java files to compile source, and use the following setting:

GENERATED_FILES_DIR = "${SRCROOT}/Generated";

HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${J2OBJC_HOME}/frameworks/JRE.framework/Headers" "${GENERATED_FILES_DIR}" "${J2OBJC_HOME}/include" $(inherited);

LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = ${J2OBJC_HOME}/lib;

OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ljre_emul

CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = NO

and I got error:

## include "J2ObjC_header.h"  >> Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'XXXXX'

Then  i do the following:

CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES

The error still exist.

I link 'JRE.framework' and  set the   HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS

The error still exist.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You also want to set `DEFINES_MODULE = NO;`

Besides that, you don't need the `"${J2OBJC_HOME}/include"` in `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` and you can also remove `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = ${J2OBJC_HOME}/lib; OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ljre_emul;` since you are using the JRE framework now.

If you are translating the `.java` sources without the `--no-package-directories` flag and you want to preserve the directory structure, then you also want to do following:

1. Add the generated files as a folder references in Xcode
2. Remove them from `Copy Bundle Resources` phase
3. Drop the folders in `Public` section of the `Headers` phase
4. Add new `Run Scrip` phase to remove the `.m` files from `Headers` directory:
   `find "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH" -name "*.m" -exec rm -f {} \;`
5. Now you can reference them in your umbrella header using `#include <your-framework-name/path/to/header/Header.h>`